# Integration by partial-fractions, I´m stuck in this one.

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

I don´t really know how get the factors in the denominator which allow me to use a case

$\int\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-x} dx$

Comment: Note: $\frac{1}{x^2-x} = \frac{1}{x(x-1)} = \frac{?}{x}+\frac{?}{x-1}$

Comment: But if I do in that way, in the part of algebra the ecuations doesn´t match.

Comment: Hint: ${x^2+1\over x^2-x} = 1+ {x+1\over x(x-1)} = 1+{A\over x}+{B\over x-1}$.

Comment: @Scoofjeer Partial fractions is certainly important, but this particular integral can also be done without any partial fraction decomposition...

Comment: one nonstandard way may be to reduce $\frac{x^2-2x+1+2x}{x^2-x}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-x}=\frac{x^2}{x^2-x}+\frac{1}{x^2-x}$$
$$=\frac{x^2}{x(x-1)}+\frac{1}{x(x-1)}$$
$$=\frac{x}{(x-1)}+\frac{1}{x(x-1)}$$
$$=\frac{x-1+1}{(x-1)}+\frac{1}{x(x-1)}$$
$$=1+\frac{1}{(x-1)}+\frac{1}{x(x-1)}$$
now let
$$\frac{1}{x(x-1)}=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x-1}$$

equate the two sides to find
$$A=-1$$
$$B=1$$
so
$$=1+\frac{1}{(x-1)}+\frac{1}{(x-1)}-\frac{1}{x}$$
$$=1+\frac{2}{(x-1)}-\frac{1}{x}$$